# jqGrid : easy way to have the refresh button

Tags: jqgrid

I just want to display the refresh button on my jqGrids. I thought it was provided naturally so I did this :

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.nav, {
    refresh: true,
    refreshstate: "current"
});
```

but it does nothing. no button appearing.

How can I add a refresh button just triggering the reloadGrid ?

thank you

Comment: You wrote first "I just want to **hide** a refresh button" and then "How can I **add** a refresh button ...". Do you want to show or to hide refresh button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.jgrid.nav` cab be used to specify **default** values of `navGrid` parameters, but to create "refresh" button or some other button in the grid you need explicitly call `navGrid` method. For example

```js
$("#gridId").jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {
    add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true
});
```

The method `navGrid` creates navigator structures in the specified pager and then places specified buttons in the navigator bar.

If you use `toppager: true` option then top pager will be created additionally. The pager will have  id = grid_id + "_toppager" (`gridId_toppager` if id of the grid is `gridId`). You can have one or two pagers. You can call `navGrid` explicitly for one from the pagers or you can use `cloneToTop: true` option of `navGrid` to place the pager on every page.

If you have existing project with many grids you have sure one common JavaScript file with settings which you included on every page. You placed sure `$.extend($.jgrid.nav, {...});` in the file. Whyt you can do is to specify common `onInitGrid` callback which calls `navGrid`:

```js
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    onInitGrid: function () {
        var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
        if (p.pager) {
            $self.jqGrid("navGrid", p.pager,
                {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true, cloneToTop: true});
        } else if (p.toppager) {
            $self.jqGrid("navGrid", "#" + $.jgrid.jqID(p.id) + "_toppager",
                {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true});
        }
    }
});
```